# How to add bleed in an image in inDesign which has important details around the edge that should not be cropped?

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, bleed

I have a page in inDesign document that i want to be fully covered by an image. I have added bleed (3mm, the page is A5 size) due to printing but if i just extend the image to the bleeding area some of the image details in the edges will be cropped. How can i avoid that? The image should cover the whole page but contains info around the edges that should be printed.

Comment: The only way to do that is to extend the image artificially. This is precisely the reason printers tell you not to put important parts of images close to the edge.

Comment: It might be helpful to add an example so we can give some ideas based on your situation. Can you photoshop/digitally paint extra details on the edges of the image? Seems odd to have important information 3mm away from the edge. There should be a little room for error when printing/cutting.

Comment: If an image contains *important* detail at the page edge, you *may* want to reconsider how the image is placed. With or without a bleed, *important* information should *never* be at the edge of a page.

Answer (score 3):

An image would need to extend over the edge of the sheet to form a bleed. So you'd need to extend the image itself if there are parts of it that you don't want to be cut off.

It's possible using content aware filling in software such as Photoshop or even free software such as GIMP. Success for this kind of automatic filling is often dependent on the kind of image. It may not work for everything. Manual cloning may be required.

Anyway, to do it, you'd need to expand the canvas, select the image, invert the selection, then in Photoshop do *Edit > Fill, and choose Content Aware*.  In GIMP this could be achieved using the Resynthesizer plugin (*Filters > Enhance > Heal Selection*).  This will essentially fill the extra space around the image, extending it.

Example in Photoshop

[image]

and in GIMP

[image]

Comment: that was exactly what i had to do , thanx!